# Is there a website for tracking people that use different apps?

Tags: tracking, websites

I'd like to compare my progress in running with the progress of various other people that I know.

The problem is that everybody uses a different mobile app for tracking their progress and there is no chance to convince them to all switch to a single app.

Therefore I wonder if there is a website that is able to grab the information from the various  tracking apps and aggregate them in one site. Is there such an application?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about apps and data aggregation. It might be better on one of the mobile or web-app SE sites.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I think this is fine, as it covers _"Gear and gadgets used during exercise"_.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that there is any such website as there is no profit for these companies in sharing their data with such an aggregator.

Although some sites work in cooperation with other sites, eg Fitocracy can pull your running data from Runkeeper and Runtastic does similar stuff, I don't know of a public API to access the data.

Even if it were possible to pull the data without such an API it would be problematic as the non public data is subject each persons privacy and as such there would be legal problems.

The only way I see is that people export their own data and upload it to a secondary site (which could be automated), but I am not aware of such a project and doubt that people would go through this effort.

Comment: It's actually a pretty cool idea... there's quite a few programmers who frequent this site (including mmmmeeee) and something like that may appear sooner rather than later since the concept has now been put out into the ether.

Comment: I would love to see something like this as I have the same problem, but I think the legal problems are … well, a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I use a fitness app called "MyFitnessPal" which is basically a colorie tracker at heart but also interfaces to a variety of running apps to show calories consumed.

You can follow this link to the MyFitnessPal website for a list of the apps which it connects to.
http://www.myfitnesspal.com/apps

Comment: Does it interface only to pull running data (and which, only calories?) for yourself or can you share your data with friends?

Comment: You can share data with friends. Here is an example from my feed:
alexk burned 550 calories doing 36 minutes of Running (jogging), 6.7 mph (9 min mile)
RunKeeper · 4 days ago · Comment

Answer (score 0):

There is no one size fits all answer.  The various running apps may integrate with MyFitnessPal, or Fitocracy.  There are some apps that also integrate with your [Withing's scale](http://www.withings.com/en/bodyanalyzer) or FitBit.  So if you run, you have options available to you.  However, if you lift, there isn't anything I'm aware of that allows you to compare and contrast across apps.  There are fairly large technical issues that affect whether this is even feasible.  For example, what units does one site use vs. another?  Are the units just a label?  This second issue is what makes JEFit difficult for me to use because it doesn't really convert metric and imperial measurements, it just slaps the unit name on the end of the number.

The bigger question is whether it's healthy for you to compare yourself against others:

- It can lend to an inflated ego if the people you are comparing against are not where you are on particular lifts.  Doesn't really help you get better.
- It can lend to a deflated ego and lack of confidence when the people who were weaker are now stronger than you and still getting better when you stay the same.  Again, doesn't really help you get better.
- Comparing yourself to other people doesn't help you become better at your goals.

The best thing you can do is compare your current training to your previous training.  If you are making progress, great!  Keep doing what you are doing.  If you aren't making progress towards your current goals, then use those logs to analyze why not.

Answer (score 0):

There are app's such as [SyncMyTracks](http://syncmytracks.com/#compatibility) that attempt to synchronize your workouts with a dozen of the main providers, and the majority of app's are adding the ability to sync with at least one of the aggregators eg. [Google Fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Fit), [Apple Health](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_(application)), [MyFitnessPal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyFitnessPal).